# How can I track referrals from offline materials using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, redirects, marketing

My client is about to issue a bundle of offline materials (leaflets, posters, etc...) for distribution to various places for PR and marketing purposes. They've asked us to create a number of special URLs that all go to the homepage of their site, through which they can identify the place where the poster was hung / leaflet handed out as the referrer. For example, different leaflets and posters might have different URLs as below:

```
www.example.com/partner1
www.example.com/partner2
```

We use Joomla as our CMS, and it's fairly trivial to use its 'Redirect Manager' to alias these special URLs to the home page so that they don't result in `404` errors.

However, I'd also like to intelligently track these URLs. Of course, I could add the standard `<code>utm</code>` Google Analytics tracking parameters onto the end of the friendly URLs, but this wouldn't be very friendly (`www.example.com/partner1?utm_source=posterCampaign&utm_medium=....`). But I would like them to flag in Google Analytics as a special type of referral.

What would be best practice in a scenario like this, other than just filtering in the Google Analytics dashboard on *pathName* or some such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Google Tag Manager then you can capture the value of the URL fragment and then match it with your Lookup Table macro. This is a much more efficient way of doing this.

1) Create a new Macro (Macro Type: URL -> Component Type: Fragment)

2) Create another Macro (Macro Type: Lookup Table)

a) enter all of your items such as location1, location2, bar5

b) use the macro from step one to match 'When {{macro1name}} equals'

3) Setup a new dimension in Google Analytics

4) Go to your Pageviews tag in GTM and under Custom Dimensions add your dimension index and the second micro.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to hide the utm tags behind a vanity short URL?

In other words, the printed/offline material would have a URL like:

ex.ly/offer1

ex.ly/offer2

Making it easier to remember/type and able to expand out to the big ugly URL that gets you the tracking you need.